selected method of worksheet class failed When Protected Massage
I want  the first sheet to be selected when Excel is opened.
the following code is works:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Menu").Select
Range("A2").Select
End sub

But when I transfer Excel to another person's system.
And the protection option is given (below photo), then it gives an error.

when clicked Enable  it gives an error.
selected method of worksheet class failed!


Check for Protected View
Ensure that the workbook is not opening in Protected View.
If it's from an email or downloaded from the internet, the file is marked as coming from an "untrusted source." You can unblock it:
Right-click the file in File Explorer.
Select Properties.
Check Unblock at the bottom and click OK.

Use Trusted Locations
If this file will be shared with others, you can instruct them to add the folder containing the workbook to Excel's Trusted Locations:
Go to File > Options > Trust Center.
Click Trust Center Settings.
Choose Trusted Locations > Add new location.
Add the folder path where the workbook is saved.
This ensures that Excel does not open the workbook in Protected View.

Avoid using 'SELECT' and add error-checking to your code, at the very least something like that:


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Menu")
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        ws.Activate
        Application.Goto ws.Range("A2"), Scroll:=True
    Else
        MsgBox "The 'Menu' sheet is missing. Please contact the administrator.", vbCritical
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

